# XQuery - Extract distinct elments by attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I have an XML document which contains a list of customers and their orders and items in those orders. I want to get a list containing distinct values of customers. The customer's id is the attribute of "Name". Example XML:

```
<customerunion>
  <Customer Name="c2">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="xyz">i10</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c3">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="qwe">i11</Item>
      <Item Description="mnb">i12</Item>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNumber="o2">
      <Item Description="cfg">i5</Item>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c1">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="abc">i1</Item>
      <Item Description="def">i2</Item>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c4">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="abc">i1</Item>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNumber="o2">
      <Item Description="def">i2</Item>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c2">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="milk"/>
 </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c10">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="chips greek yogort avacado"/>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c4">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="tea bags cheese"/>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c11">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description=" milk sushi Notebook "/>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c11">
    <Order OrderNumber="o2">
      <Item Description="grape tomato"/>
    </Order>
 </Customer>

 <Customer Name="c12">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="bread"/>
    </Order>
 </Customer>
</customerunion>
```

and below is the result I want to get:

```
<customerlib>
  <Customer Name="c1">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="abc">i1</Item>
      <Item Description="def">i2</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>

  <Customer Name="c2">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="xyz">i10</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>

  <Customer Name="c3">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="qwe">i11</Item>
      <Item Description="mnb">i12</Item>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNumber="o2">
      <Item Description="cfg">i5</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>
  <Customer Name="c4">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="abc">i1</Item>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNumber="o2">
      <Item Description="def">i2</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>
  <Customer Name="c10">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="chips">i1</Item>
      <Item Description="greek yogort">i2</Item>
      <Item Description="avacado">i3</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>

  <Customer Name="c11">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="milk">i1</Item>
      <Item Description="sushi">i2</Item>
      <Item Description="Notebook">i3</Item>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderNumber="o2">
      <Item Description="grape tomato">i1</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>

  <Customer Name="c12">
    <Order OrderNumber="o1">
      <Item Description="bread">i1</Item>
    </Order>
  </Customer>
</customerlib>
```

I used the following XQuery:

```
let $customer := doc("customerunion.xml")/customerunion/Customer
let $allcustomername := doc("customerunion.xml")/Customer/@Name
for $uniquecustomer in distinct-values($customer/@Name)
let $order := distinct-values($customer[Name=$uniquecustomer]/Order)
let $item := distinct-values($customer[Name=$uniquecustomer]/Order/Item)
where $uniquecustomer = $allcustomername
return 
 <customerlib>
    {$uniquecustomer/..}
    {
      for $o in $order
      return $o
    }
    {
      for $i in $item
      return $i
    }
 </customerlib>
```

However, I got no results from running the query. Can you help me to modify to the XQuery to get the desired result?

Comment: For one thing, your first line of XQuery has `/customerunion/` whereas the XML has `<customersunion>`: there is an `s` in the middle of the element name. Your second `let` statement leaves out `/customersunion/` completely. For these reasons, your first two variables will contain nothing.

Comment: Please do some basic debugging _before_ asking a question. Only run the first line (and return the results), if it's fine, proceed to the next line (or logic code block, or whatever a reasonable basic unit would be).

Comment: To add to Jens' rightful comment, you might be interested to know about the `fn:trace()` function, which you can use for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly it seems to me that you are asking to group all of the Orders into distinct Customers?

If so, in eXist-db you can use the `group by` expression from XQuery 3.0. So the following query should work for you:

```
<customerlib>
{
    let $customers := doc("customerunion.xml")
    return
        for $customer in $customers/customersunion/Customer
        group by $customer-name := $customer/@Name
        order by substring-after($customer-name, "c") cast as xs:integer
        return
            <Customer Name="{$customer-name}">
            {
                $customers/customersunion/Customer[@Name eq $customer-name]/Order
            }
            </Customer>
}
</customerlib>
```

I have also added an `order by` expression, as the results that you showed were ordered. However this works based on the fact that your Customer Names are always of the format `cN` where N is some number. If this is not the case, you will need to adjust or remove that line from the query.